# Not able to delete an email account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I entered an IMAP email into my Outlook (it is not the only email account I have). I then realized, I did not want it in my account so I went to Tools/Account Settings/Email Tab and deleted the file. I rebooted the computer and then re-opened outlook. It is still showing up in the left hand side of my accounts. Outlook is taking significantly longer to boot, and when I try to delete the Data File in Tools/Account Settings, it tells me that the data file is associated with an email account and to remove it on the Email tab, but there is no email account for it listed on the email tab.

I also opened the files where my psts are held and deleted the account there, but each time it opens outlook, it recreates that account.

Any thoughts on how to delete the email account once and for all?

Comment: Delete it from within control panel

Answer (score 1):

Right click on in in outlook and choose "Close ..." from the resulting context menu.  Then Delete the file.  If that does not work go into the "Mail" control panel, click Show Profiles, and delete and recreate your profile.

Comment: When I hit close it says that the account is linked to data files and I need to go to the tabs section and remove.  That is the same issue I am having now.  There are three emails listed in the emails tab and 4 data files listed in the data tab file.  When I try to delete the unwanted data file it says that I have to delete the email but it does not currently exist in that list.

Comment: You must have a corrupted profile.  So delete it and recreate it.  I have solved many an Outlook issue that way.  You will have to re-setup the three accounts you do want, but if they are Exchange or IMAP that will go quickly.  I usually give the new profile a name different from the old profile, just in case outlook does not delete something it should.  You can also just create a new profile and leave the old profile intact.  Then you can refer to it if you can not remember a setting.  And then set outlook to always open the new profile.